# prevent back in browser when coming from external url

Tags: javascript, browser, back

I have a frontpage and a lot of subpages showing portfolio projects. when clicking a thumbnail on front page, you will enter the linked sub page.
On that sub page i have a close button, with a "back in browser" function.
That works fine, but I want to prevent this action when coming from another site outside my domain, otherwise they will get sent out of my site.
ao instead of them going back in browser, I would need them to go to ../index.html, when clicking that back button.

I use this in my HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
```

Comment: Why not have an anchor tag with `href` pointing to your landing/index page?

Comment: Why would you offer a button that does the exact same thing as a button the user already has? Think about where `Close` should _really_ go.

Comment: @Bhavik : its because when using a back function like that i end uo in the same position where i was on the page as where i came from, not just on top of the page again. its important when browsing the porfolio.

Comment: @Halcyon : please have a look at my page and you understand... design.ovesandersen.com
its about moving forth and back on the portfolio part

Comment: From what I can see 'close' just goes to the homepage. If I open one of the pages in a new tab the close button doesn't go anywhere because there is no history element.